# Service and DAO method parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I have a DAO interface to get object for the database :

```
List<MyObject> find(String id)
```

In my service, I need to extend this object with additional fields coming from configuration and/or other DAOs.

```
List<MyObjectEx> find(String id)
```

How should MyObject and MyObjectEx relates to another. Derivation, aggregation, field mapping, other ? (I can also imagine having DAO returning partial MyObjectEx instances)

Thanks !

Comment: If possible create a composition. I will advice against a VO inside other -- one table, one VO keeps life sane.

Comment: What should happen to `MyObject`? Will it be used somewhere?

Comment: may be in your service impl can do this. Once you get response from DAO for `MyObject`, do your additional fields config or other DAOs in the same service impl function.

Comment: @DerMike MyObject will not be exposed in the service interface but it may still live in the DAO implemention's cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It may not be a derivation because MyObjectEx is not a type of
   MyObject. Rather it's a different type of object which contains
   properties present in MyObject. But if MyObjectEx may be used in
   places where MyObject is required then we can keep them in the same
   hierarchy.
2. You could use Adapter pattern but I don't think it'd be appropriate
       as this is not exactly object transformation in the true sense.
3. Also, we can think about aggregation but then the MyObjectEx and
       MyObject will not be able to replace each other i.e. the benefits of
       point #1 would be lost.